# Failing to get jQuery delegation working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery delegation to work with dynamically created elements.

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<div id="pagination" class="pagination light-theme simple-pagination" data-bind="pagination: { pagingInfo: pagingInfo }">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><span class="current prev">Prev</span>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><span class="current">1</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-2" class="page-link">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-3" class="page-link">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-4" class="page-link">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-5" class="page-link">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">…</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-26" class="page-link">26</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-27" class="page-link">27</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-2" class="page-link next">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where the  element and its children are created dynamically after the page has finished loading.

I want to attach an event handler to the  elements with the code displayed below

```
$("#pagination").on("click", "a", function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

For some reason I can't get this to work. If I change to "mouseenter" the event handler works correctly, but I need to capture click events.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've found a possible reason for this problem. I'm using a jquery plugin to create the pagination (simplePagination.js). It's possible that the plugin prevents events to propagate. I will investigate this further.

Comment: So `pagination` doesn't exist when you're calling `.on()`?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code

Comment: @CrazyTrain in this case mouseenter wouldn't work too as i understand it

Comment: If you just changed the `click` to `mouseenter` and it worked, then there is most likely another problem, that has to do with some other code.

Comment: it work well on me. what jquery version u used?

Comment: @roasted: Good point. I didn't notice that. That's strange.

Comment: Don't forget to clear your cache, just in case...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zMUFB/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F5fwb/#tidy here's my testing. it works well.

Comment: @Simon: Hopefully you'll respond to some of these comments. But are there any other event handlers bound to the `ul` or `li` elements that call `.stopPropagation()` or that do `return false`?

Comment: Where are you attaching event handler?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I've tried go attach the same event handler to both the li and ul elements and then it works correctly. No other event handlers are attached to these elements.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I must correct myself: when I attach event handlers to the li or ul elements clicks are captured. But when I attach to the a element within the li element clicks are not captured.

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for logging/debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prevent the event in the first place so that you won't get redirected:

```
$("#pagination").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```